# How can I intercept videos uploaded with react-filepond in a Next.js app to convert them with fluent-ffmpeg before uploading them to S3?

Tags: javascript, next.js, ffmpeg, filepond, fluent-ffmpeg

I'm working on a Next.js app where users can upload videos using react-filepond. Currently, the uploaded videos are immediately uploaded to an S3 bucket without any modifications. However, I'd like to intercept the uploaded video file, use fluent-ffmpeg to convert it to a specific format, and then upload the converted video to the same S3 bucket.

I'm not quite sure where to start with this. Here's what I've considered so far:

- Using FilePond's onprocessfile callback to intercept the uploaded file and pass it to a function that uses fluent-ffmpeg to convert it. However, I'm not sure how to get the file data from FilePond and pass it to the conversion function.
- Using Next.js' API routes to handle the file upload and conversion separately from the main app logic. However, I'm not sure how to set up the API route to receive the uploaded file from FilePond.

I appreciate any guidance or resources you can share. Thank you!